# Working with form fields with special chars in their ids

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have an Asp.Net MVC site where I have to integrate a 3rd party API, which expects a HTTP POST with specified fields, some of which are like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ITEM[0]" value="somevalue" />
```

I must fill these values in C# code (for example Page_Load event etc) and cannot change the field names, and there can be more than one item entity, as in ITEM[0], ITEM[1] etc.

Problem is Visual Studio does not allow special chars in field names and thus I can't use them in C#.

Is there any way to get around this and have such fields in the form?

Thanks all.

Comment: The `name`, not the `id` attribute determines the name used for POST/GET variable keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem to have hidden field with `name="ITEM[0]"`. The name attribute is used by POST/GET like `CodeCaster` said in his comment.

There is no problem with this line:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" name="ITEM[0]" id="ITEM1" value="somevalue" />
```

Change the `id` to not represent array, this is the problem in the `id` naming. !

Comment: Thanks, I think I can come up with something using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

if You specified name to input elements as

```
<input type="hidden" id="ITEM[0]" name="ITEM[0]" value="somevalue" />
```

then You can access these values on Server Side

```
string Item1= Request.Form["ITEM[0]"];
```